# How to not make my border move when it changes colors?

Tags: html, css

So basically, I'm there changing the color of my border, and all of the sudden it re scales and it's smaller than before, but the rest doesn't re scale.

The code is the following:

```css
#MM {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: rgb(255, 25, 0);
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="MM" onclick="Mining()"><img id="MMI" src="EnemyPhase1.png"></button>
```

This is the result(the image is a placeholder):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case is add a box-sizing property.
this can help mitigate any unwanted changes.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: you could also consider using outline instead of border: For example outline: 1px solid orange;

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but one is to edit the `box-sizing` property. For example: use `border-box` for the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Isn't that more or less the same as the other answer?